# Richard K. Guy, the centenarian mathematician

Tags: discussion

Professor [Richard K. Guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_K._Guy), the great number theorist had passed away long before in [March](https://aperiodical.com/2020/03/richard-k-guy-1916-2020/). Since there were no posts to commemorate him on this site (as far as I saw), I decided to post this question here. It would be great if some colleagues post their experiences here as regards his mathematical and other achievements. I was actually inspired by his book, *Unsolved Problems in Number theory*.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Perhaps not so well-known was Richard's production of chess problems. [Here's one][1] from 1944. 


  [1]: https://www.chess.com/forum/view/daily-puzzles/5-24-2019-richard-k-guy-british-chess-magazine-1944

Comment: Here's a tribute to Richard on the occasion of his 100th birthday: http://nautil.us/blog/an-infinitely-rich-mathematician-turns-100

Comment: Here's an obit that pays particular attention to Richard's mountaineering exploits: https://gripped.com/news/canadian-climbing-legend-richard-guy-dies-at-103/

Comment: The journal *Crux Mathematicorum* announced a special issue dedicated to the memory of the professor. See page 97 of Crux Mathematicorum Vol. 46, No. 3 (March, 2020) from the corresponding web page of the journal.

Comment: Link to the March 2020 issue of Crux: https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=46&issue=3

Comment: I add that the mentioned issue was the corresponding to October 2020 of *Crux Mathematicorum* (by the Canadian Mathematical Society). It seems that there are more sites remembering the professor but I'm not the one who can to add more information (I'm not a professional mathematician).